# How can I save client-side content-editable updates to mongodb database in node.js express app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

What is the best way to persist user-generated data with NodeJS, Express, and MongoDB?

I'm building my first web-app using this stack (with bootstrap HTML/CSS and JS for the frontend) and I've realised that I need a data-binding solution. I'd rather avoid a complete rebuild of my front-end so it seems like React will be the best option, but I'd rather find out now if I'm missing something obvious.

The app will allow users to create 1-n documents, generate 1-n new components within them, and edit 1-n content-editable elements within those components.

I'm at the point where I've built the server, db, and frontend and the users and documents persist, but the components and their content does not.

The functionality I would like is that, when a user generates a new element or exits the contenteditable area of that element, any changes they have made will persist. I'd like to achieve this without a bazillion API calls.

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may create page description in markdown and then render it to react components.
For example you can check https://www.gatsbyjs.org/ plus Remark Custopm blocks plugin - https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-custom-blocks/

Comment: Seems to me using gatsby would require significant rebuild?